# Assigning a value to the checkbox (true or false)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, checkbox

How do I set a value to the checkbox, true or false.

```
<%    Boolean inactive = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("isCheckedUnmatch"));
boolean isChecked = inactive.booleanValue();
%>

<script language = javascript>
function chgFlag(isChecked){
alert(isChecked);
isChecked = true;
}
</script>

<td align = "left">
<input name = "chkUnmatch" type = "checkbox" value = "<%=isChecked%>" onclick = "if (this.checked==true){chgFlag(<%=true%>)}">
<font face = "verdana" size = "2"><b>Unmatch Payment</b></font>
</td>
```

I have tried this code and even if I checked the box, the value of the boolean from the java controller is still false, its default value.

NOTE: I am using Java 1.3, the latest version of Java when the application was developed.

Comment: input tag is missing and font tag is not closed properly. Assigned id atribute of input tag as "isCheckedUnmatch".It is better if you write onclick function as a separate.

Comment: I tried Arvind and drkunibar's inputs. None worked.

Comment: Why yout try to get `request.getParameter("isCheckedUnmatch")`? Shouldn't it be `request.getAttribute("isCheckedUnmatch")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in JSP java codes and Scriptlets (`<% %>`, `<%! %>`, `<%= %>`), expression `${}` etc.. all are processed before the HTML, javascripts and css are processed.

> even if I checked the box, the value of the boolean from the java
>   controller is still false, its default value.

If you want to change the server side variable value (i.e. Controllers, Models, Servlets etc) on checked/unchecked of a checkbox, there is some ways:

**1)** Use a AJAX to send a request to server for variable value changes:

HTML page like:

```
<form id="myForm" action="servletUrlPattern" method="post">
    <input name="chkUnmatch"
        type="checkbox"
        onclick="if (this.checked==true){chgFlag(true)}">Check Box
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function chgFlag(isChecked){
     console.log('isChecked: '+isChecked);
     $.post( $('#myForm').attr('action'), { valueToChange : isChecked }).done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
      });
 }
</script>
```

and in Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("doPost() invoked..");

    Boolean valueToChange = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("valueToChange"));
    System.out.println("valueToChange:"+valueToChange);
    //Here, Do your works..
    response.getWriter().write("successfully changed.");        
}
```

**2)**

Use form with submit button.

---

See also:
[jquery post doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is Java 1.3, a legacy application that I am supporting.

Comment: @coferniecus this should work fine for Java 1.3. what happens any error or exception you got?

Answer (score 1):

u may try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkUnmatch" onclick="chgFlag(this.checked)" value="" id="box"/>

<script>
  function chgFlag(chk){
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    box.value = chk;
  }
  <%
  Object tmp = request.getParameter("isCheckedUnmatch");
  if (null != tmp) {
    boolean mrk = Boolean.valueOf(tmp);
  %>
    chgFlag(<%=mrk%>);
  <%}%>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

**EXSAMPLE**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function refreshCheckboxValue(checkbox){
                checkbox.value = checkbox.checked;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="refreshCheckboxValue(this)" value="false"/>
    </body>
</html>
```